# Convert sympy Symbol to string such that it can always be parsed?

Tags: python, json, parsing, sympy

I'm looking for a way to convert an arbitrary sympy symbol to a string such that it can later be parsed back into the same symbol. For example, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy import Symbol

A = Symbol("A")
B = Symbol("B")
pathological = Symbol("A B")
parsed = parse_expr(str(pathological)) # this raises an error
assert parsed == pathological
```

Instead of parsing `str(pathological)` as representing the `pathological` symbol, the parser parses `A` and `B` separately and we get the following error:

```
File "<string>", line 1
Symbol ('A' )Symbol ('B' )
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a way to create an escaped string from `pathological` that is guaranteed to be parsed back to `pathological`?

The reason I am trying to do this is so that I can store sympy expressions as JSON and reconstruct them. If there is a completely different way to do that, I would be happy to hear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such symbols I would store the `srepr()` form. It may be too much to store that for the whole expression so perhaps it would be useful to make a custom printer that does what StrPrinter does except when necessary falls back to ReprPrinter. See https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the pathological symbols before they are converted to strings then you can create a "kerned" version that will parse ok and pass the kerned version with the desired version in a `local_dict`. `re.escape` will put a backslash in front of the space and the kerned version will replace that `\` with something unique:

```
>>> kerned = re.escape(str(pathological)).replace('\\ ','_kern_')
>>> d = {kerned: pathological}
>>> parse_expr(kerned, d)
A B
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your solution fixes the particular case where the symbol includes a space, but there are other cases that remain broken, such as if the symbol starts with a number, includes a hyphen or certain other symbols. I don't even know what all the cases are, so I was hoping there was a sympy aproach that covers every case.